# Canada Visitor Visa - VAC fees

Tags: visas, canada, fees-and-charges

I applied to Canada visitor visa online and paid CAD$100 fees. Now they are asking me to send the passport to Los Angeles processing center. The website says to pay VAC fees, if applicable.

Do I need to pay anything else while I submit my passports? I can't find proper information on the canada immigration website.

Any recent experiences?

Answer (score 4):

There are [two separate fees](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/fees/result.asp?countrySelect=IN&lob=trv) you might have to pay when applying for a Canadian visitor visa.

The first is the application fee for the visa itself. You pay this online directly, when you apply online for the visa. This costs $100 CAD.

The second is the $85 VAC biometrics fee. You pay this fee only if you need to visit a VAC to give biometrics in order to complete your application. You also need to pay the VAC fee if you submitted a paper application through the VAC instead of submitting it online. In this case the VAC will collect both fees.

Finally, the VAC may add its own service charge onto the top of the above fees.

If you are not a national of one of the [countries from which Canada requires biometrics](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/biometrics.asp), you can apply and pay ($100) online, and should not need to visit a VAC; you will deal with the visa office directly.

In your case, it appears that you are not a national of one of those countries, and you have already paid the visa application fee online, so you only need to mail your passport to the visa office.

Comment: You cannot send your passport directly to the visa office unless you have a diplomatic or official passport. http://www.cic.gc.ca/submit-envoyer/offices-bureaux-eng.asp#U

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Canadian Embassy is only accepting Diplomatic and Official passports directly. All other passports should be submitted to Visa Application Center only.

In my case, though there is no biometric fees to be paid, I should pay USD$31.19 VAC fees. The VAC fees should be paid by certified check or money order and sent to following address.

CSC Consular Services Inc
P.O. Box 410039
Salt Lake City, Utah 84141-0039

A photocopy of this check along with passport, prepaid return AWB and other documents should be sent to:

Visa Application Centre
2120 E. Grand Avenue, Suite 108A
El Segundo, CA, 90245
U.S.A.

it's too complicated :(

Comment: What a complete nightmare this process is. I hope you get your visa in the end.

Comment: Did you get your visa after paying the VAC fees? I am in the same boat and I can't figure out if I am supposed to pay the VAC fees or not.

Comment: yes, I did get my visa and I paid the VAC fees.

Comment: How do they link the check that's sent to VAC PO box with the application package that's sent to El Segundo? Do we make a copy of the check and send it with the application package?

Comment: I did send a copy of copy of the check with the passport.

Answer (score 1):

VAC fees do not have to be paid unless you have not paid the biometric fees. You also have to pay the VAC fee if your biometrics was done at another VAC center than the one you send your documents to. Found out the hard way :(

Also do not include prepaid fedex return envelope. They only accept if you buy fedex services through them. Another 38 USD lost. I wish the instructions were clear.